# Magento Order in which modules affect a quote

Tags: magento, checkout, cart

I have a module (not created by me) which picks up a quote and applies a discount if certain criteria are met. This works fine on it's own. The shopping cart rules also work fine on their own.

However, I need the custom module to apply relevant discounts before the built in Magento shopping cart (total price) rules are applied. As it stands the Magento ones apply first, and then the custom ones, leading to Magento discounts when there shouldn't be.

What controls the order of the modules, and thus how would I specify a different order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Magento has the `collectTotals` functional (I believe this is realization of the Composite pattern). What it basicly does - is address each of the specified *Totals Collectors* in order and call it's `collect()` method.

Most likely the total collector for your module is called after the `SalesRule` one (which  has code **discount**). So what you need to do: open the `config.xml` configuration file of the custom discount module, find the xpath *config/global/sales/quote/totals/[the module alias]* and add (or change if it exists) the directive `<before>discount</before>`

In that way you're ordering the total collector of the custom module to apply discounts before the `SalesRule` one.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, there wasn't any `before` directive, so I added one below the `class` one, but it doesn't seemed to have had any effect, unfortunately. There is also a `<events><sales_quote_save_before><observers>`, not sure if that is relevant at all.

Comment: it's possible that the functional you've described is done in the Observer. you can try changing `<sales_quote_save_before>` to `<sales_quote_collect_totals_before>` - so the custom module logic will be applied before the `collectTotals` process, but it's possible that your _Quote_ object will not contain even subtotal..

Comment: Well that's strange; made the change you suggested, but now get a 500 error (php fatal error memory exhausted) when adding to the cart or visiting a non-empty cart. Is there any other information I could provide that would help nail it down. Thanks for the answers too, really appreciate that.

Comment: probably the logic in the Observer require some info which is not available at the moment `sales_quote_collect_totals_before` event is dispatched. now I'm out of ideas, it would be helpful, if you post the `config.xml` file of the module you're working with, - but I'm not sure whether it will help or not, you need to use some debugging tool

Comment: Slayer, it turned out that the other discount module wasn't using the normal magento promotion sytems, but had defined its own; as such the order wouldn't solve it. But no reason to think your solution wasn't correct for the situation I seemed to describe, hence correct answer. Thanks.